# How to read variables in Powershell from a GitHub text file

Tags: powershell, github

I have a text file in GitHub at a location like: https://github.com/raw/my-account/my-project/paths.txt

The text file contains key-value pairs separated by an '=' sign like:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

I want to gather these variables into my Powershell script. If the text file is local I can do it with:

```
Get-Content paths.txt | Foreach-Object{
   $var = $_.Split('=')
   New-Variable -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]
}
```

To read the text file from GitHub I tried replacing 'paths.txt' with the GitHub location of the text file surrounded by double-quotes. However, it says a drive letter 'https' cannot be found.

How can I read the text file from GitHub and store the variables into my Powershell script?

Comment: You'll need to use `Invoke-WebRequest` and explore the parameters to get the output you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-StringData) (Version 3.0+):

```
$webRequest = Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/raw/my-account/my-project/paths.txt
$paths = ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $webRequest.Content
```

`$paths` is now a hashtable with a key per unique name in the input data:

```
PS C:\> $paths['key1']
value1
```

Comment: If that $paths['key1'] needs to be inside of double quotes how can I get the value? It was printing out System.Collections.Hashtable['key1'] when placed in double quotes.

Comment: "Like this: $($paths['key1'])"

Comment: Just learned of a more streamlined way to do this. From the standard view of a file in github, click on the "Raw" button to get to the raw view of the file.
e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user-name/repo-name/branch-name/paths.txt

Since only the content is needed, can use `Invoke-RestMethod` (Version 3.0+) to access it directly.


`$url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user-name/repo-name/branch-name/paths.txt'`


`$paths = Invoke-RestMethod $url | ConvertFrom-StringData # same result`